# JSLint : How to resolve Expected '\s' and instead saw ' '. warning

Tags: javascript, jslint

Below is my js code and i get **Expected '\s' and instead saw ' '**. error. Can somebody help me to resolve this error.

> osVersion = /Mac OS X (10[._\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];

Comment: Have you tried `/Mac\sOS\sX\s`?

Comment: JSLint really says that?  That's... surprising?  Surely that changes the meaning of the regex substantially, from looking for a single space to one of a number of different whitespace characters?

Comment: @Justinas: You are right. I tried that. It is working. Can u mention this as a Answer. I will accept your answer.

Comment: @James Thorpe: Yes. it says. Also it throws warning as 'Unexpected '\' before '.'. in the line osVersion = /Mac\sOS\sX\s(10[\.\_\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JSLint complains about whitespaces not being *regexed* replace all whitespaces with `\s`

```
osVersion = /Mac\sOS\sX\s(10[._\d]+)/.exec(nAgt)[1];
```